# Cómo filtrar solo el mes de una fecha

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Esto es lo que quiero

```
ng-repeat="pago in pagos | filter: { fecha.getMonth() : 06}"
```

pero exactamente no se como obtener el mes de la propiedad fecha porque así: `'fecha.getMonth()'` me dio error , y tampoco se si puedo filtrar así, por favor oriéntenme.

Comment: `fecha` es una propiedad perteneciente al `$scope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) podemos indicar si mostrar cierto elemento o no en el `ngRepeat`.

Primero debemos de especificarle que funcion es que filtrara los datos. En este caso `filtrarPorFecha`:

```
ng-repeat="pago in pagos | filter:filtrarPorFecha"
```

`filtrarPorFecha` ahora recibira el parametro pago. En el retornamos `true|false` si mostrar el elemento o no.

```
$scope.filtrarContenido = function(pago){
    return pago.fecha.getMonth() == fecha.getMonth();
}
```

Y listo:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  
  $scope.pagos = [
    {
      fecha : new Date(2017,0,20),
      cliente : "James Moriarty"
    },
    {
      fecha: new Date(2017,6,20),
      cliente: "Jhon Wick"
    },
    {
      fecha: new Date(2017,2,20),
      cliente: "Neo"
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.fecha = new Date(2017,2,8);
  
  $scope.filtrarContenido = function(pago)
  {
    console.log(pago);
    
    return $scope.fecha.getMonth() == pago.fecha.getMonth();
  }
  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  
  <div ng-repeat="pago in pagos|filter:filtrarContenido">
    {{pago.fecha}}
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo que encontre en una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29242080/1595451) a una pregunta similar en inglés

Nótese que la línea similar a lo que estas buscando es

```
<li ng-repeat="a in appointments | filter: selectedMonthFilter">id: {{a.id}}, label: {{a.label}}, created: {{a.created}}</li>
```

La cual llama a

```
$scope.selectedMonthFilter = function(element) {
    if(!$scope.selectedMonth) return true;
    return element.created.getMonth() == $scope.selectedMonth;
  }
```

Que ha su vez `$scope.selectedMonth` es el valor seleccionado en la lista desplegable.

Aquí el código completo:

Nota: Comenté un par de líneas del HEAD pues no se requiren en Stack Snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.appointments = [];
  
  $scope.selectedMonth = "";
  
  $scope.selectedMonthFilter = function(element) {
    if(!$scope.selectedMonth) return true;
    return element.created.getMonth() == $scope.selectedMonth;
  }
  
  function randomDate(start, end) {
      return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
  }  
  
  for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    $scope.appointments.push({id: i, label: "Item number " + i, created: randomDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date())});
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> -->
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    Show results for 
    <select ng-model = "selectedMonth">
      <option></option>
      <option value="0">Jan</option>  
      <option value="1">Feb</option>  
      <option value="2">Mar</option>  
      <option value="3">Apr</option>  
      <option value="4">May</option>  
      <option value="5">Jun</option>  
      <option value="6">Jul</option>  
      <option value="7">Aug</option>  
      <option value="8">Sep</option>  
      <option value="9">Oct</option>  
      <option value="10">Nov</option>  
      <option value="11">Dec</option>  
    </select>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="a in appointments | filter: selectedMonthFilter">id: {{a.id}}, label: {{a.label}}, created: {{a.created}}</li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```